# JTable adjust column and row width according to Data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to show the below data in a Jtable cell.As of now everything comes in a single line even-though i'm overriding the object's toString method with newline characters.How can I set the Jtable to adjust the cell height and width depending on the data.

```
Segment ID: 1  
Elevation : 2.0 
Azimuth :30.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to embed a JTextArea object within a JTable cell